# Symfony 5.3: LexikJWT: Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured

Tags: symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle

On localhost the app works perfectly, but when I put it on the apache server, I get this error:
"Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured."

Security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        refresh:
            pattern:  ^/api/token/refresh
            stateless: true
            
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/token/refresh, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Routes.yaml

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

Any idea why I have this error on my server?

Answer (score 0):

```
guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

that snippet is for versions before 5.3. To enable jwt authenticator try:

```
jwt: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

in symfony 6.2 i fixed the error by adding some configurations in the security.yaml
check it out :
https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle/issues/307#issuecomment-1487595410